# Arduino python serial can't solve simple error

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I recently started working with Python.

I have to use arduino and raspberry pi serial communication for a sensor project and I wanted to experiment with the data I created before the sensors came. I will send a total of 8 data from the arduino and I am facing a problem while sending this data.

arduino code:

```
void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {

Serial.println(String("255") + "," + String("255") + "," + String("255")  + "," + String("21.651")  + "," + String("25.152")  + "," + String("12.051")  + "," + String("168.125") + "," + String("120"));
delay(1000);
}
```

arduino side, the first three data will be between 0-255. The next 4 data will be floats and the last data will be integers. So this is the data from the sensors, and I'm sure.

On the python side, it's like this:

```
import serial
com = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
com.reset_input_buffer()

while True :
   sensorData = com.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
   temp_array = str(sensorData).split(',')
   a = temp_array[0]
   b = temp_array[1]
   c = temp_array[2]
   d = temp_array[3]
   e = temp_array[4]
   f = temp_array[5]
   g = temp_array[6]
   h = temp_array[7]
   print(c)
```

The error I am encountering is as follows:

```
  File "/home/gorkem/Desktop/process/8data.py", line 9, in <module>
  b = temp_array[1]
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

if i try to print sensorData it prints blank data once or twice. What could this be due to?

```
gorkem@Gorkem-MSI:~/Desktop/process$ /bin/python3 
/home/gorkem/Desktop/process/8data.py

0,0,0,21.651,25.152,12.051,168.125,120
0,0,0,21.651,25.152,12.051,168.125,120
0,0,0,21.651,25.152,12.051,168.125,120
0,0,0,21.651,25.152,12.051,168.125,120
0,0,0,21.651,25.152,12.051,168.125,120
```

Comment: Can you print out the `seonsorData` you're getting on the Python side?

Comment: Unrelated, but `str(sensorData)` isn't necessary since `sensorData` is already a string.

Comment: @GörkemGök _please please_ put all info like that in the post itself, not in comments (there's no formatting in comments)

Comment: @GörkemGök so if it printed as blank, that means that your script is reading blank values and then trying to split on a comma, right? Wouldn't you want to not do the split if you don't read in any data? Obviously it would fail if there was no data to split and then put into `temp_array`...

Comment: @RandomDavis split can work on any string even without the delimiter being present in the string at all, the problem is that there's no list with all of the 7 data in case of any empty response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import serial
com = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
com.reset_input_buffer()

while True :
   sensorData = com.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
   temp_array = str(sensorData).split(',')
   if len(temp_array) > 7:
       a = temp_array[0]
       b = temp_array[1]
       c = temp_array[2]
       d = temp_array[3]
       e = temp_array[4]
       f = temp_array[5]
       g = temp_array[6]
       h = temp_array[7]
       print(c)
```

I'd recommend doing something like this to ensure that every line that it's reading actually contains those 7 inputs.

Comment: I did as you said. If it only gives this error on the first run, it may be a solution. Are there any cases of data loss after this?

Comment: Shouldn't be, if there's a data loss, that's a problem on the Arduino's side. Either check for temp_array length manually or just generate a dict with the sensor data temp_array.

Comment: @GörkemGök you could always log bad data somewhere so you can later make sure nothing was missed